# Override registration page problem

Tags: users, theming, 7

I'm trying to customize the user registration page in a zen subtheme.
The template candidates files suggested by themer devel are page-user.tpl.php and page-user-register.tpl.php, but when I try to create them, page.tpl.php (placed in the subtheme as well) is not overridden.
All other pages are working fine.
I've clean theme registry and checked all file permissions, I still can't get this.
What did I miss?

Comment: same problem here, did you find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

If you're using D7, you'll need two dashes between page-user, not one.

[Some examples](http://drupal.org/node/1089656)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm on D6. Themer devel gives me the templates candidate names, but they don't seems to work.